# Adding Html Code Dynamically to a div

Tags: asp.net

```
private void GetGroupListHtml()
{                
                //...Code omitted
                String htmlCode = String.Empty;

                foreach (DataRow _DataRow in _DataTable.Rows)
                {
                    htmlCode += @"<div class=""box collapsed-box"">
                         <div class=""box-header with-border"">
                             <h3 class=""box-title"">
                                  <asp:Label ID=""groupTitleLabel"" runat=""server"" Text=" +_DataRow["groupName"] +  @"""></asp:Label>
                             </h3>
                             <div class=""box-tools pull-right"">
                                 <button class=""btn btn-box-tool"" data-widget=""collapse"" data-toggle=""tooltip"" title=""Expand""><i class=""fa fa-plus""></i></button>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>";
                }
}
```

I want to add the htmlCodes to a div. Is it possible to do it this way? Basically i have a string variable which appends the html codes. I want to dump this code in between the div tag and return the new webpage to the user.

```
<div id="groupListDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for concatenating strings instead of using the `+=` sign.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<...>"); // Your html code
```

After that if you want to append this generated html to your page, use a `<asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlCode"></asp:Panel>` tag that is located on your page where you want to add the html code.

Then in your code behind simply do:

```
this.pnlCode.Controls.add(new LiteralControl() { Text = sb.ToString() });
```

This takes your html as a string, put it into a control and then append it to your panel onto your page.

Comment: there is no problem use div also

Comment: Correct, but I prefer using ASP.NET controls

Comment: Hi it works. Then how do i code a click event for each of the button in the htmlCode. <button class=""btn btn-box-tool"" ><i class=""fa fa-plus""></i></button>

Comment: That you should ask in a new question because its about a new problem.